# Manual array copy in a nested for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I trying to find all 2s, move them to the back of the array, and turn them into 0s without loosing the order of the array. For example, [1,2,3,2,2,4,5] would become [1,3,4,5,0,0,0]. My code works fine but the IDE is telling me that the nested for loop is copying the array manually and wants me to replace it with `System.arraycopy()`. How would I go about that?

Code looks like this:

```
    int[] numbers = {1,2,3,2,2,4,5};
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if (numbers[i] == 2){
            for (int j = i; j < numbers.length - 1; j++){
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
            }
            numbers[numbers.length-1] = 0;
            i --;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your IDE suggests that, there might be a functionnality to automatically replace your code. If it's IntelliJ, did you try `alt` + `enter`?

Comment: but your code does more than just copy the array as is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statement:

```
for (int j = i; j < numbers.length - 1; j++){
    numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
}
```

Can be replaced by:

```
System.arraycopy(numbers, i + 1, numbers, i, numbers.length - 1 - i);
```

IDEs like IntelliJ should suggest that automatically when you press `alt` + `enter` (default key combination).

---

### Now about [`arraycopy()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm)

From the documentation, [`java.lang.System.arraycopy()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm) will copy n elements (last argument) from the source array (1st argument) to the destination array (3rd argument) with the corresponding indexes to start from (2nd and 4th arguments).

More specifically, when calling `arraycopy(numbers, i + 1, numbers, i, numbers.length - 1 - i)` the arguments are:

1. `numbers`: The source array.
2. `i + 1`: The starting position in the source array.
3. `numbers`: The destination array.
4. `i`: The starting position in the destination data.
5. `numbers.length - 1 - i`: The number of array elements to be copied.

In your case, elements will be copied from your array, to itself, but the fact that source starting position is shifted from the destination starting position will induce the global shifting you're after (moving elements to the *left*).

About the number of elements to be moved, it should move `i` elements minus the first one that doesn't move and only gets overwritten. Hence the `length - 1 - i`.

Comment: You should also consider taking a look at the other answers about optimizing your code after you've understood this piece of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop could be replaced with an `arraycopy`, however, you don't need an inner loop:

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,2,2,4,5};
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if (numbers[i] != 2){
        numbers[j++] = numbers[i];
    }
}
while (j < numbers.length) {
   numbers[j++] = 0;
}
```

UPDATE

Or even:

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,2,2,4,5};
int j = 0;
for (int n: numbers){
    if (n != 2){
        numbers[j++] = n;
    }
}
Arrays.fill(numbers,j,numbers.length,0);
```

Comment: In my opinion the best implementation among those posted here, since this one has a O(N) runtime (versus O(N2) in the question) & O(1) space overhead. One slight modification could be to replace the while loop at the end with: Arrays.fill(numbers,j,numbers.length,0);

Comment: @Aloke fair enough

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is pretty simple: if you can *reduce* the lines of code you are responsible for (for example by using utility methods such as `Arrays.arraycopy()`) - then do that.

Keep in mind: each line that you write today, you have to read and understand tomorrow, and to probably modify in 5 weeks or months from now.

But then: I think you are **over-complicating** things here. I would use a *temporary list*, like this:

```
List<Integer> notTwos = new ArrayList<>();
int numberOfTwos = 0;
for (int i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
  if (source[i] == 2) {
    numberOfTwos++;
  } else {
    notTwo.append(source[i]);
  }
}
... simply append `numberOfTwo` 0s to the list, and then turn it into an array
```

You see: you are nesting **two** for-loops, and you are repeatedly copying around elements. That is inefficient, hard to understand, and no matter how you do it: way too complicated. As shown: using a second list/array it is possible to "solve" this problem in a **single** pass.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing your inner loop with System.arrayCopy the code should look like:

```
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5 };
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == 2) {
            System.arraycopy(numbers, i + 1, numbers, i, numbers.length - 1 - i);
            numbers[numbers.length - 1] = 0;
            i--;
        }
    }
```